# Trying to convert a regression program from stata to python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stata, linear-regression

I currently have this do file in stata which is a simple test for significance in a matched pairs regression. I understand some basic python but I did not know if something like this is possible in python given my limited knowledge. I am using this for my uncle who is using python for his company. If anyone can guide me to some resources or explain how I would do this please let me know.

```
*import delimited "data"

drop if missing(v1,v2,v3)

regress v3 v2

test v2

generate pvalue = r(p)

if pvalue > .01 {
display "notsig"
display pvalue
}

if pvalue <= .01 {
display "sig"
display pvalue
}

drop pvalue
```

Comment: The variable `pvalue` is not needed as you can condition on `r(p)` The test is given in the `regress` output any way.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into `pandas` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) and `statsmodels` (http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html). Pandas is good for reading data into dataframes in python, and then you can run statistical models with statsmodels. I am not well-versed in statsmodels, so you may have to look into the documentation yourself.

Here is an example, to try and go along with what you showed in your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",")
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')

results = sm.ols(formula="v3~v2", data=df).fit()
t_test = results.t_test('v2=0')

if (t_test.pvalue*2) > 0.01:
  print("notsig")
  print(t_test.pvalue*2)

if (t_test.pvalue*2) <= 0.01:
  print("sig")
  print(t_test.pvalue*2)
```

I took the pvalue*2 in this example, because I believe that it only gives the one-tail p-value, but you should check the documentation to make sure.

Comment: tvalues and pvalues for testing that parameter is zero are directly available in the results instance, t_test is more general and provides the same results.

Comment: The pvalue is for two-sided hypothesis, the alternative is no equal, so the `*2` needs to be removed. (Currently the test in the model results are always two-sided, only the standalone t_tests for means allow for one-sided alternatives.)

Comment: `statsmodels` is misspelled (without an "l")

Comment: @CPBL Thank you, I edited it to show the correct spelling.